# How to include objects into the simulation of the wave modifier or replicate the wave modifier

Tags: fluid-simulation, ocean-simulation

My scene is a ocean with an ANT Landscape in the middle serving as an island. There is also to be a boat and some sort of serpent in the ocean, which is a plane with a ocean modifier. Currently, the ocean overlaps some parts of the island like its not there and the waves pass through the boat. Later on, when I finish up the serpent mesh, I want to create a splashing effect and cause the waves to rise around the serpent as it threads through surface.

However, there isn't any settings I can mess around with to fix this. I've looked up a [solution using the shrink wrap modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-can-waves-of-the-ocean-simulator-flattened-on-a-beach-area), but that creates a mess of triangle and still doesn't do everything I want it to do. I considered fluid simulation, except for the warning that fluid simulation takes a long time and its used sparsely.

I was wondering, therefore, if it was possible to replicate the ocean modifier and then join the meshes by joining the closest vertices? Or if there is some workaround involving some complex modifiers? Or if I should fake the effect of all objects being in the same scene?

Comment: The ocean modifier only affects the object it's on. If you want interactions with other objects, you'll need a fluid simulation. However in this case you can probably fake the splashing with particles.

Comment: @gandalf3 Do you know how I can replicate the effects of the ocean modifier? Is there any particular setup with wind for the simulation?

Comment: for particles or fluid?

Comment: @gandalf3 The fluid simulation, though I was also wondering how I could fit the particles and fluid  smoothly together(I'm assuming that I'll have to create another plane for the particles unless I'm wrong and the simulation can also be a particle system.)

Comment: Unfortunately no, the current fluid simulator is quite limited. There is a new one called mantaflow being integrated into blender as part of the gsoc with forcefield support, but that probably won't be here for a little while.. There is the existing SPH simulator which has force field support, but there is no good way to mesh the result yet. You could try creating a fluid object from an ocean modifier, then maybe using some hack with fluid control objects to simulate wind or other forces..